# Using 7-zip to add folders to separate archive (windows)

Tags: batch-processing, 7zip

With Winrar I can use this command for create archives for each folder

```
for folder in */; do rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
```

I use windows and I want cloning this command using 7z Console because software is more strong. 
I try also this batch

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%A IN (*) DO "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma2:d256m "%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
```

but archive me only files, not separated folders.

Answer (score 5):

Solution [here](http://it.wikihow.com/Usare-7zip-per-Creare-Pi%C3%B9-Cartelle-Compresse-in-una-Sola-Volta)

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```